# How to store as a file, a small clip within a song being played using VLC Media player

Tags: vlc-media-player, media-player

If I am playing a song in VLC Media player 1.1.7(On Win-7). I select points A and B to loop between that points while playing back, I want to store the clip of the song between point A and B as separate song/file.

How can I do that using VLC player?

Any other player would allow me to save and store clips/portions of a large song being played?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure VLC can do that, but then I don't use it so don't take that as gospel. It sounds to me like you are looking to extract a loop from an audio file and if that is the case then you'll need an audio editor. The one that springs to mind is Audacity, found here: http://audacity.sourceforge.net/

I don't have it installed unfortunately but it should be as simple as opening your sound file, making a selection and then either copy or cut into a new document. I generally use Soundforge to do the same thing but essentially the sequence is the same.

Here are some references on looping in Audacity that may help:

http://audacity.sourceforge.net/onlinehelp-1.2/reference.html

http://forum.audacityteam.org/viewtopic.php?f=13&t=2820

http://wiki.audacityteam.org/wiki/Looping

Comment: Audacity , worked like a charm. Although exporting a selection from Audacity needed lame_encoder dll, which I downloaded. Thanks.